# What does the return value do on the render function?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, underscore.js-templating

I think this source code speaks for itself, it creates a new view.
Every time I find a tutorial there is this return value on the render function.
But I never understood what it does, my code always worked with or without that return value, what does it exactly do?

```
  // renders individual todo items list (li)
    app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',
      template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
      render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this; // "enable chained calls" whatever that means
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does what you say, it enables chain calls that means you can invoke multiple method calls.

The most common use I've seen in Backbone it's calling `el` after `render`.

```
var view = new TodoView();
('#todo').append(view.render().el);
```

But you could create any other method in your view and chain it together.

```
view.render().method1().method2()
```